# xindy repeats pages for range and single like this 1,2,2

Tags: indexing, xindy

I would like the following code to produce `hi, 1, 2`

```
\index{hi|(}%
\pagebreak
\index{hi|)}%
\index{hi}%
```

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. That Maks it a lot easier for others to test your issue when one does not have to guess 2/3 if the document